# Footer text overflow on 4 columns. How do I prevent?

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a four column footer that works fine until the browser window is shrunk.

The 2nd column(Div ID fourth) then would start push text under one of the other boxes:

It's easier to see on the website: Teetimelawn.com

I tried a few solutions but they usually end up pushing the div for fourth under near the other 3 inline div columns.

Here's the CSS info:

```
.footer {
    background-color: #336600;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    height: 350px;
    color: #F7F7F7;
    min-width: 1400px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 350px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#third {
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}


#first {
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#second {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#fourth {
    height: 100%;
clear: none;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="footer">
 <div id=third>
   <h1>Site Map
   </h1>
     <p1>
     <a href="/index.html">Home page
</a>  <br>
<a href="/estimate.htm">Estimate Form
</a>  <br>  <p1>
<a href="/lawncare.html">Lawn Care Process
</a> <br>
 <p1>
 <a href="/trees.html">Tree And Shrub Control
</a> <br>
 <p1><a href="/pestcontrol.html">Pest Control Services
</a> <br>
 <p1><a href="/sprinkler.html">Lawn Sprinkler ervice </a> <br>
 <p1><a href="/paybal.php">Secure Online Bill Pay
</a>  <br>
 <p1>
 <a href="/careers.html">Careers And Team
</a> 
 <p1>
<br>
 <p1>
 <a href="/testimony.html">Customer Testimony And Lawn Gallery
</a> 
<br>

 </div>
  <div id=first><div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Tee Time Lawn Care</h1>
  <br>1566 Frontage Rd
O'Fallon, IL 62269</p1></a>
<br>
    <p1 itemprop="telephone">(618) 632-8873<br>(636) 272-8873</p1>
    <br>
<br>
   <p2 itemprop="description"> A local lawn and landscaping company with an emphasis on safe, organic lawn care. Lawn care companies like us will treat your lawn and yard like a golf course so give us a call if you need the best lawn in your neighborhood. </p2></div>
  </div>
 <div id=second> 
   <h1>Lawn care company service in  Missouri, Illinois (MO, IL)<br>
  St. Louis suburbs including:</h1>
      Fairview Heights lawn care, Fairview Heights landscaping<br>
      St. Louis lawn care, St. Louis landscaping<br>
      Edwardsville lawn care, Edwardsville landscaping<br>
     Granite city lawn care, Granite city landscaping<br>
      Saint Charles lawn care, Saint Charles landscaping<br>
      Belleville lawn care, Belleville landscaping<br>
      Collinsville lawn care, Collinsville landscaping<br>  O'Fallon lawn care, O'Fallon landscaping<br>
      And nearby  towns and cities for your yard service needs.<br><br>

  </div><div id=fourth>
  <h1> Our lawn care and landscaping services include:</h1>
 <p2>Organic and granular fertilization, aeration and seeding, pest control, tree and shrub maintenance service, soil conditioning, heat guard, summer recovery, root rejuvenation, winterizing, blanket barrier, mole removal, yard cleaning, lawn and yard mowing, commercial landscaping, weed removal, weed prevention, vole removal, and more!
 <br> Please contact us for additional services.</p2>
  </div>
  <!-- end .footer -->

</div>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/108985556811751806647" rel="publisher">Google+</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change the `padding` in `#fourth`  div id into margin like this:

```
margin-right: 20px;
margin-left: 10px;
```

UPDATE : I create [**This Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/edisutrisno/CKdyT/) for example of my latest comment.

Comment: Thanks, but no change

Comment: well, try to change the footer width. e.g 95%.

Comment: Change the `#first`, `#second`, `#third` and `#fourth` width in to `percent (%)`. e.g if the curent width is 180px change to 18%. just play arround with that. but remember, if all the div width in footers summed, make sure the result is not more than 95%. last, set footer width to 100%.